# how add comments into listview in recycler view.Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview

i need to put comments on click button into listview, but i am using recycler view adapter.

i get this error:

```
Error:(200, 54) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(<anonymous OnClickListener>,int,ArrayList<String>)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,String[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List<String>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
```

THIS IS THE CODE:

```
holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //holder.lw.setA
           String commento= (holder.tw.getText().toString());
           // holder.lw.setAdapter(adapter);
             ArrayList<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);

            arrayList.add(commento);
            // next thing you have to do is check if your adapter has changed
            holder.lw.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

    });
```

Someone can help me?
THANKS

Comment: Replace `this` with `context` in the line `final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);`

Comment: @Chithra there isn't context...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "**this**" with **Context** in the line

```
 final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
```

**pass the context in your VideoAdapter**

```
 VideoAdapter videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter (this);
```

**Constructor of VideoAdapter**

```
  public VideoAdapter (Context context) {
       this.mContext = context;
    }
```

**intialize like this**

```
 final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
```

As you can see that the constructer of ArrayAdapter require Context instead of the onClickListener refrence

**Note: You can pass as many argument in the your VideoAdapter constructor this is just a way to show you how to pass the context.**

Comment: i stay in VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.VideoHolder>